# Ruby Blog Engine like toto

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, blogs, toto

Is there any other ruby blog engine like toto which could be easily deployed on services like heroku?

If yes, Please suggest some names.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean this Toto: http://goo.gl/lxIlR ? If not, perhaps you should link to or explain briefly what Toto is. ;)

Comment: http://cloudhead.io/toto - NOT TOILET SEATS!

Comment: Why not use Toto itself? http://www.rubyinside.com/deploy-blog-with-toto-and-heroku-2962.html

Comment: That I could use.. But I need to test some alternatives too so that I could be sure :P

Answer (score 1):

I would Radiant CMS, [this how to install it on Heroku](https://github.com/radiant/radiant/wiki/Installing-on-Heroku). It has a great blog built right in.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout scanty and jekyll really small and fast ... hackers style blogging engine.~

https://github.com/adamwiggins/scanty

https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll